# Testing in an ActiveStorage context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rails-activestorage

In following the [rails guides regarding testing](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#testing), the following was effected for two classes that have attachments (using a french naming variant, which is close enough to the reserved 'file')

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :fichier do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_limit: [100, 100]
    attachable.variant :small, resize_to_limit: [250, 250]
  end
[...]
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :fichier
```

The controller testing is effected with the same pattern as follows (for each class):

```
post pictures_url, params: { picture: { fichier: file_fixture_upload("space_chen.jpg", "image/jpg"), individual: individuals(:one), shop_id: shops(:one).id, individual_id: individuals(:one).id } }, xhr: true
[...]
post documents_url, params: { document: { fichier: file_fixture_upload("find_shipment.pdf", "application/pdf"), title: 'title', shop_id: shops(:one).id, individual_id: individuals(:one).id } }, xhr: true
```

storage.yml configuration follows the prescribed:

```
test_fixtures:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage_fixtures") %>
```

Out of security `space_chen.jpg` and `find_shipment.pdf` files were added to the fixtures/files directory.

the `fixtures/active_storage/attachments.yml` set of fixtures is *one are where the naming convention is opaque to this reader*

```
document_fichier:
  name: find_shipment
  record: fichier (Document)
  blob: fichier_find_shipment_blob

picture_fichier:
  name: space_chen
  record: fichier (Picture)
  blob: fichier_space_chen_blob
```

while `fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml`

```
fichier_find_shipment_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob filename: "find_shipment.pdf", service_name: "test_fixtures" %>

fichier_space_chen_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob filename: "space_chen.jpg", service_name: "test_fixtures" %>
```

In launching controller tests for either class, invariably the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `file_fixture_upload' for #<PicturesControllerTest:0x000000010ca46278>
[...]
NoMethodError: undefined method `file_fixture_upload' for #<DocumentsControllerTest:0x00000001082dac90>
```

The documentation starts out by stating:

```
  test "can sign up" do
    post signup_path, params: {
      name: "David",
      avatar: file_fixture_upload("david.png", "image/png")
    }
```

What is amiss?

Comment: Does [`include ActionDispatch::TestProcess::FixtureFile`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/FixtureFile.html) fix the issue?

Comment: No that returns the same error.  The subsequent answer, however does. Odd as `fixture_file_upload` is an alias for `file_fixture_upload`. would this qualify as a bug?

Comment: i guess your rails version is amiss, you're following "edge" guide. you should follow the same version of a guide as your rails version. `file_fixture_upload` added in rails v7.1.0. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6cafc49d2c3c9a1c429cf70048eaa16b1ed6ba0a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you use `fixture_file_upload` instead of `file_fixture_upload`?

```rb
post api_v1_create_business_card_path, params: {
  front_image: fixture_file_upload('business-card.jpg', 'image/jpg'),
  back_image: fixture_file_upload('business-card.jpg', 'image/jpg'),
  language_hints: %w[en ja fr]
},
```

Like so: https://github.com/tonystrawberry/matomeishi-rails.jp/blob/main/spec/requests/api/v1/business_cards_spec.rb#L151

**Rails version: 7.0.8**

Comment: It certainly does.  and is is surprising given that the one that works is quoted as being an alias to the former.  I surmise that is not the case then.